# Azure DevOps and Git Fetch Failed With Error

Tags: git, azure-devops, gitlab

I have created Azure DevOps pipeline but it is failing on git checkout,

```
Starting: Checkout repository@Dev to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Syncing repository: repository (ExternalGit)
Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
git version
git version 2.39.1.windows.1
git lfs version
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
git init "D:\a\1\s"
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/a/1/s/.git/
git remote add origin http://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.http://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git.extraheader
git config --get-all http.extraheader
git config --get-regexp .*extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git remote set-url origin http://***:***@gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git
git remote set-url --push origin http://***:***@gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git
git fetch --force --no-tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab.mycompany.net/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git/'
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 6.062 seconds before retry.
git fetch --force --no-tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab.mycompany.net/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
```

But if I run the same command in any command line it is working fine,

```
C:\Users\Imran\repo>git version
git version 2.32.0.windows.2

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git lfs version
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users//Imran/repo/.git/

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git remote add origin http://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config gc.auto 0

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config --get-all http.http://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git.extraheader

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config --get-all http.extraheader

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config --get-regexp .*extraheader

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config --get-all http.proxy

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git config http.version HTTP/1.1

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git remote set-url origin http://username:pass@gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git remote set-url --push origin http://username:pass@gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git

C:\Users\Imran\repo>git fetch --force --no-tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.mycompany.net/mycompany/myapp.git/
remote: Enumerating objects: 54107, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1844/1844), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (138/138), done.
```

[image]

I have selected MAC and it works but with Windows its showing error.

Comment: can you share how you have setup the pipeline to checkout?

Comment: @Sibtain Azure DevOps built-in (ASP.NET). Updating my answer to include screenshot

Comment: How did you authenticate to GitLab, what credentials did you enter? It looks like a username + password. But it should have been a username + access token. Try updating the service connection.

Comment: Tried these combinations. It working with MAC but not with windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that when I copy gitlab repo URL, it includes http. I changed the URL to **https** and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use https instead of http while fetching git repositories from github to azure.